# Bessel-like equation problem with NDSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following nonlinear ODE, but Mathematica takes forever to give a result. Any idea why?

```
 eq = f''[r] + r^-1 f'[r] - r^-2 f[r] + (1 - r^2) f[r] == 0
 g[r_] = f[r] /. NDSolve[{eq, f[0] == 1, f[1] == 1}, f[r], {r, 0, 1}] //First;
 Plot[g[r], {r, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: I recommend to use `DSolve` without boundary conditions. Then try to expand solutions with `Series` eg. `Series[sol,{r,0,3}]`. Then it should appear resonable what might go wrong (branch cuts of complex functions). There is also option in `NDSolve` to avoid symbolic preprocessing.

Comment: Your code throws some warnings, but runs on my computer in 1 second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your equation has terms singular at `r=0`, while you fix one of the boundary conditions exactly in this point. The workaround may be in shifting the first boundary condition a bit out of this point:

```
    ClearAll[r];
eq = f''[r] + f'[r]/r - f[r]/r^2 + (1 - r^2) f[r] == 0;
nds = NDSolve[{eq, f[0.1] == 1, f[1] == 1}, f[r], {r, 0, 1}] // First
Plot[f[r] /. nds, {r, 0, 1}]
```

yielding this:

[image]

Alternatively you can regularize the equation by dividing terms by `r+0.001` instead of dividing by `r`:

```
    ClearAll[r];
eq = f''[r] + f'[r]/(r + 0.001) - 
    f[r]/(r + 0.001)^2 + (1 - r^2) f[r] == 0;
nds = NDSolve[{eq, f[0] == 1, f[1] == 1}, f[r], {r, 0, 1}] // First
Plot[f[r] /. nds, {r, 0, 1}]
```

returning this:

[image]

It is up to you to decide which approach is better.

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

Because something is wrong with the boundary at $x=0$. Let's solve the equation with `DSolve`. Since `DSolve` has trouble in dealing with `f[0] == 1`, we first use a more general b.c. `f[a] == b`:

```
eq = f''[r] + r^-1 f'[r] - r^-2 f[r] + (1 - r^2) f[r] == 0    
{generalasol} = f[r] /. DSolve[{eq, f[a] == b, f[1] == 1}, f[r], {r}];
```

and take the limit:

```
asol = Limit[asolgeneral, a -> 0]
```

> ```
> (E^(1/2 - r^2/2) LaguerreL[1/4, -1, r^2])/(r LaguerreL[1/4, -1, 1])
> ```

Somewhat surprisingly, we found the solution doesn't depend on the value of `b` at all, and the resulting graph is:

```
Plot[asol, {r, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

It's actually in agreement with the numeric result given by Alexei. If you've tried different shift for the left boundary, you would have found the offset drastically influence the result:

```
Manipulate[Plot[
  f[r] /. NDSolve[{eq, f[e] == 1, f[1] == 1}, f[r], {r, e, 1}] // First // Evaluate, {r, 
   e, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], {e, 10^-4, 0.1}]
```

[image]